# Difference between Vector2 and Vector4

Tags: c#, xna

I started learning about XNA game studios today and was wondering what's the differences between `Vector2` and `Vector4`

Thanks :)

Comment: What does the documentation on the two classes say on the subject?

Comment: Defines a vector with two components and Defines a vector with four components. I thought the Vector2 would be for 2D, but then why is their Vector4 and not Vector3 since 3D only used 3 coordinates, hence why I have asked on here, and got a excellent answer explaining why. No need to be an ass about it. Started game programming a few hours ago, everyone has to start somewhere. There is no need for all the vote downs.

Comment: So you already knew the difference; you knew that a `Vector2` has 2 components and a `Vector4` has 4.  So it seems what you *really* want to know is,  "Why would anyone want a vector with 4 components instead of just 2 or 3?"  That's at least a slightly better question that's not so trivial to answer, given that there are no remarks in the documentation for `Vector4`.  You'd still want to demonstrate some research into that question though, as you are currently basically just asking us to google stuff for you because you were too lazy.

Comment: Stack Overflow, along with all of the other sites on this network, have very high quality standards that they demand of the questions and answers posted on the site.  Posts which do not meet those standards tend to be downvoted, closed, and/or deleted.  It is not a site where any and all questions can be asked and answered.  These restrictions are in place so that when a good question is asked, it is *much* more likely to get good answers, as well as to create a high quality repository of knowledge.  If you are unwilling to ask high quality questions then this is not the site for you.

Comment: Well to be honest, majority of my questions are of a very high quality. But this was a simple question which only needed a simple answer (Which I got). You can't really make this question a super high quality without starting to write 'bullshit' to make it seem like it's 'high quality'

Comment: The reason that it's a low quality question is because you did insufficient research before asking it.  You could have taken the 30 seconds (which, by the way, would be much less time than it takes to write the question here) to look at the documentation of the two classes and see how they were different.  If you had already done that then asking us to tell you something you already know is helping no-one.  As I said before, it seems that what you *really* wanted to know is not what you asked, but rather, "Why would anyone want to use a `Vector4` class; when is it useful?" or some such.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Vector2` contains 2 float-components. It is used mainly for 2D graphics (2D -> 2 components)

`Vector4` contains 4 float-components. It is used for 3D graphics (in an 3D affine space, 3D affine transformations can be done using [homogeneous coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) (4 components))

Comment: `Vector4` can also be used as a substitute for `Tuple<Vector2, Vector2>` and `Rectangle` with `float` values instead of `int` for each four elements (though you can't access them by `.Width` for example), it can save your time.